# when hover is removed the div content hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here i have a menu now the issue is when i hover on any li it shows some content on the left side but as the hover is removed then the content is hidden 
[here is the link](http://csinfotech.co.in/csi2/)  now when we hover on the menu product then on hostpital management system and if we want to go to  reduce amount of paper work it hides the li i want to show the detali 
here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav li").hover(function() {
    var datatoShow = $(this).attr('data');
    $("#" + datatoShow).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products<span class="icon ion-ios-arrow-down pull-right"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <li>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="left-area">
                <button type="button" class="btn all-product-btn">All Products</button>
                <hr>
                <ul id="nav">
                  <li class="active-class" data="Employee"><a href="employee-monitoring-system.html">Employee Monitoring System</a></li>
                  <li data="Hospital"><a href="hospital-management-software/index.html">Hospital Management Software</a></li>
                  <li data="School"><a href="school-management-system/index.html">School Management System</a></li>
                  <li data="Inventory"><a href="inventory-management-software/index.html">Inventory Management Software</a></li>
                  <li data="Fee"><a href="fee-management-system.html">Fee Management System</a></li>
                  <li data="Lead"><a href="lead-management-system/index.html">Lead Management System</a></li>
                  <li data="Customer"><a href="customer-relationship-management.html">Customer Relationship Management</a></li>
                  <li data="Human"><a href="human-resource-management-software.html">Human Resource Management Software</a></li>
                  <li data="Enterprises"><a href="enterprises-resource-planning.html">Enterprises Resource Planning</a></li>
                  <li data="Commerce"><a href="customize-e-commerce-portals.html">Customize E-Commerce Portals</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Employee" class="col-sm-8 nav-hide">
              <div class="right-area">
                <h3>Employee Monitoring System</h3>
                <p></p>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                  <ul>
                    <li>A Unique System that peforms employee monitoring.</li>
                    <li>Prevents unauthorised exchange of data</li>
                    <li>Could not be identified by a user</li>
                    <li>Captures their Keystrokes</li>
                    <li>Caputres their Screen Shots</li>
                    <li>Uploads text files</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5"><img src="img/products/ems.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <div id="Hospital" class="col-sm-8 nav-hide" style="display:none">
            <div class="right-area">
              <h3>Hospital Management Software</h3>
              <div class="col-md-7">
                <ul>
                  <li>Reduces the amount of paper work.</li>
                  <li>Recording information about the Patients that come.</li>
                  <li>Generating bills.</li>
                  <li>Recording information related to diagnosis given to Patients.</li>
                  <li>Keeping record of the Immunization provided to children/patients.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-5"><img src="img/products/hospital.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </ul>
      </div>
```

here  [how it should  work](https://www.ibm.com/in-en/)

it should work excatly like this menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nav li").hover(function() {
   var datatoShow = $(this).attr('data');
   $(".nav-hide").hide();
   $("#" + datatoShow).show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with some **[CSS trickery](https://schier.co/blog/2014/10/23/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-using-the-hover-selector.html)** by **[Gregory Schier](https://schier.co/)** in this case.

You can play around with your own project by applying some animations and easings that happen at the moment of the `:hover` event to make it look like IBM India's website's example.

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;

    list-style: none; /** Remove list bullets */
    width: 100%; /** Set the width to 100% of it's parent */
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

/** Button Styles **/
.dropdown button {
    background: #FF6223;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em 0.8em;
    font-size: 1em;
}

/** List Item Styles **/
.dropdown a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    color: #333333;
}

/** List Item Hover Styles **/
.dropdown a:hover {
    background: #BBBBBB;
}
```

```html
<!-- dropdown container -->
<div class="dropdown">

    <!-- trigger button -->
    <button>Navigate</button>

    <!-- dropdown menu -->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```